# Firestore access rules don't report any error when they deny access

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have a Flutter app using Firestore, Auth isn't used yet, i.e. the app will attempt unauthenticated access. It all seems to be configured correctly as in general it works, both on Android and iOS - I can get the eata. I just see some strange behavior when I change the access rule to one which should result in an 'access denied'.

Side note: the Firebase project is actually configured to use Firebase Auth with Google Sign In, and it works in the real app, I just completely removed the code for this to test the strange behavior.

The application:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: Screen(),
    ),
  );
}

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  StreamSubscription<dynamic> _sub;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAsync();
  }

  Future<void> _initAsync() async {
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print('>>> currentUser.uid: ${user?.uid}');
    print('will start listening');
    _sub = Firestore.instance.collection('categories').snapshots().listen(
        (querySnapshot) {
      print('>>> got data: $querySnapshot');
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((documentSnapshot) {
        print('>>> ${documentSnapshot.data['name']}');
      });
    }, onError: (error) {
      print('!!! got error: $error');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sub?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

With the following rule;

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

it works, I get the data. However, when I change the rule to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The output (starting from a freshly reset simulator):

```
flutter: >>> currentUser.uid: null
flutter: will start listening
```

then it just does nothing, no error ever comes.

**Strange thing #1**: for some reason, I need to uninstall the app and install it again, otherwise I can still get the data (I'm using the iOS simulator).

**Edit**: as explained below by Frank, this is due to a cache from previous app runs. I managed to disable the cache using this code:

```dart
await Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```

and now the data doesn't appear, as I expected to begin with. (I'm not recommending disabling the cache, it's just for understanding.)

**Strange thing #2**: when I uninstall and install the app again, I get no data, but neither do I get any kind of 'access denied' error, that I would expect. The application subscribes, and then nothing ever happens, nothing comes back from the stream.

**Edit**: the following code results in an error:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('categories').getDocuments().asStream().listen(...)
```

but it just results in a single event, as it converts a future. There are a log of bugs reported to Firestore about errors, the umbrella issue is here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1223, and the more specific issues to my case: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2334 and https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1465. Again, Frank below found the issues.

**Strange thing #3**: when I change the rule to again allow all access and start the app again, it all works again, I don't have to remove and install the app again.

**Edit**: this can again be explained by the cache/persistence.

(I did wait some time in between the checks as Firebase console told me it could take up to a minute for the rules changes to take effect.)

Questions:

1. Am I not supposed to get some kind of an indication that access was denied? It is not bad in this sample app, but in my real app, there is no way for me to know that I should somehow react and direct the user to login or whatever else. I simply don't ever get any error, and the app just sits there, showing a loading indicator. I do see 'total denies' number growing the 'Monitor rules' view in Firebase console. The rule also fails in the playground, when I test an unauthenticated call.
2. Why does the app keep getting data even after the rule has been changed? Why is uninstalling it necessary?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore client caches any data it sees in a local disk cache, so that it can show that data faster the next time it's requested. On that local disk cache the security rules of your database are not enforced (as it wouldn't help much anyway).

So the reason you have to uninstall/reinstall the app is to get rid of the data in the disk cache. You typically only have this problem during development of your security rules, which is one of the reasons you should do so before shipping your app to regular users.

---

If a read operation is not allowed due to the security rules, your `onError` will be called and in your case prints a message. You'll typically want to set an error message to the state here and render that.

Note that it is possible (in your case here) that the main callback for `listen` fires with the data from the cache, and that a bit later the `onError` fires with the rejection from the server.

Comment: "If a read operation is not allowed due to the security rules, your onError will be called and in your case prints a message." Well, that seems to be the problem: I am expecting just that, but it never happens, my onError callback is never called. I removed the app, I even erased everything, installed the app again (so there should be no cache, no auth lying around), and all the app shows is the 'will start listening' line.

Comment: To summarize: the has no auth, no data is ever printed out, just the 'will start listening' line, and the error never arrives.

Comment: I've never seen Firestore allow a read that shouldn't be allowed, so we'll have to keep troubleshooting until we find what's going on in your app. Can you `var user = await auth.currentUser(); print(user.uid);` rifght before you read from Firestore, and include the code and output in your question?

Comment: Did as you asked. auth is null. It's not that Firestore allows a read, it actually doesn't because no data is returned. It's just that no error happens, either. Thank you for your time BTW.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1223

Comment: More specifically: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2334, which has been merged into the single issue you pointed out.

Comment: One more question if you have time, about data caching: if the user is logged in and gets data, then logs out - this means Firestore would still return the cached data, right? I guess no application would not allow the call to get the documents be called again by a signed out user, but in theory it would happen, wouldn't it?

Comment: This: 'Firestore.instance.collection('categories').getDocuments().asStream().listen(...)' correctly results in an error, but it is a stream of only one data event, not really what I'm after. As a side note, getDocuments() supports a 'Source source' parameter, which allows disabling the cache. The 'snapshots' method doesn't support this.

Comment: It is correct that `snapshots` does not allow a source, as its logic is as I describe in my answer: it'd first return the local data, and then later (if there are changes) return the data from the server - or an error. It's that last part that doesn't seem to happen here.